# regex for only unique lines

Tags: regex

I have a text file with repeated lines and i want the ones that are only shown once

```
AAAAA
AAAAA
BB
BBBBB
BBBBB
CCC
CCC
D
```

note: at any time theres only duplicate lines right next to eachother and max of 2

I would only need the following two lines from it:

```
BB
D
```

I'm using a text editor (Sublime Text 3), that supports RegEx, not a programming language, so It has to be just a 1 line expression.

I know there's a way to do it easily on a UNIX terminal but if there's a regex solution it'd be more useful to me

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM1pN1/1)

Comment: This is doing exactly opposite of OP's requirement. Any special reason to do so ?

Comment: Because then the duplicate lines can be replaced with nothing leaving the desired lines un blemished...

Comment: this is the opposite of what i was looking for but still works for the purpose i need it, its probably better than what i was looking for actually

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime:

```
(?s)(.*)[\r\n]+\1[\r\n]+
```

?s -> multiline regex.

(.*)[\r\n]+ -> something followed by newlines.

\1[\r\n]+ -> The same line as before, followed by newlines.

Edit: obviously, just replace with empty string, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex:

Find What:

```
(?s)^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

Replace With:
    `blank`

This will lead to some blank lines, I'm sure you can easily take care of those.